# Is it possible to use prepared statement as part of the select expression?

Tags: mysql

I want to create the following query if possible at all

```
SELECT
   value,
   formula,
   (PREPARE stmnt FROM formula;
    EXECUTE stmnt USING value)
FROM table1
```

The formula field values are hardcoded MySQL prepared statement in a DB. Let me know if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you can :-

- `SELECT` a function

or

- `call` a stored procedure from within
  another stored procedure

if that helps at all (which it probably doesn't).

Comment: Thanks. I was a long shot anyway, :) . Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

http://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/mysql-prepared-statements-and-php-experiment/

ref this, it may help. you can't use prepare directly in a select statement..